# How to know my No. Of Questions/Answers/Accepted for today/week/month?

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers

When I MouseOver on my name, I got following information for now:

```
           today    week    month
reputation  0        45     868
votes cast  13       30     478
revisions   0        0       0
favorites   0        2       9
```

Can we know that how many non-wiki answers/questions I posted for today/week/month. Or how many of my answers are accepted for today/week/month.

**For Example:**

```
         today  week    month
answers    5     30      70
questions  2     10      15
accepted   2      7      20
```

**Here:**

```
answers   means "My non-wiki answers" 
questions means "My non-wiki question" 
accepted  means "My non-wiki answers which are accepted by Question poster"
```

**These information keep me track that what is the progress of my reputation by my posts.**

I searched it here also but did not find any other related question. Can someone provide details.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

May be we have some other ways to know these information. But I think it is basic information that a user should have quick access. I think **No. Of Answers** is more useful than **revisions** and **favorites** in this popup window. In my profile, Most of the time my **revision** and **favorite** digits are 0

Comment: No feedback from any Admin ???

Comment: That popup already takes forever to load when I have a bad cell signal.  Please don't increase the size of it -- and yes I often prefer the non-mobile site.  Further, I suspect the hope is that users *will want to notice* if several of their questions are being edited.  Or if their favorite questions are changing dramatically.</rant> that said, I would like to see **accepted** added.  Especially with negative numbers when my answers are getting *un-accepted*.

Answer (score 2):

You can [search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search) for things like [your unaccepted non-CW answers (`user:me is:answer isaccepted:0 wiki:0`)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3ame%20is%3aanswer%20isaccepted%3a0%20wiki%3a0) and [browse by date (`newest` tab)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3ame%20is%3aanswer%20isaccepted%3a0%20wiki%3a0).

There's a point where the user-friendly UI gives up. You can use the [API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/) to go beyond that. For example, you can retrieve [your questions](http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/user-questions) or [your answers](http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/user-answers) or a few other filters in a certain date range, and filter the results in any way you like.

Going even further, there's a [read-only copy of the database](https://data.stackexchange.com/) where you can make queries. It's only updated every 1–2 months, but allows you to make very fancy selections.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want to know my current week's **reputation** with my current week's No. of **answers**. For now it is showing **reputation**, **votes casts**, **revisions** and **favorites**. I think **reputation** and **votes casts** are OK but **No of Answers** and **No of Questions** are more important for me than **revisions** and **favorites**. So I think there should be a quick access to these information for a user.